# Windows Phone App - Reactiveness while not active

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am doing a little feasibility study for a Windows 8 Phone app. I am an experienced .net programmer but I am not familiar with some of the w8p concepts yet. I read quite some of the documentation and have some questions that I couldn't find clear answers for.

The questions are about continuing some of the app's logic while it isn't active. I want to add that the app would require very little processing power.

1. Is it somehow possible to make frequent updates to the app's primary or secondary tile, like once a second? Just to show some sort of counter or timer.
2. Is it possible to schedule a reactivation of the app at a certain point in time? I saw the alarm or reminder  notification, but that requires the user to tap the alarm window in order to restart the app. ( I want to add that this is potentially annoying behavior, but in this case the user would explicitly want the app to pop up at a certain time.)
3. Since I suspect that point 2 might not be possible, I want to ask whether there is some way to have the alarm or reminder dialog without a snooze button, since that doesn't suit the app's logic.  Or at least give the app an opportunity to react if the user presses snooze.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. only when the app is running. When the app is not running you can only use a background agent to update the tile once every 30 minutes
2. not possible
3. not possible

Comment: Help, that sounds like wp8 isn't suitable at all for apps with some multi tasking feeling! What would be the point to update the tile while the app is running? Is the tile visible at all then?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use [tile notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx) to set your app's primary tile's title, caption and counter. You may also do that locally when the app is active ([local notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207047(v=vs.105).aspx) and [ShellTileSchedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule(v=vs.105).aspx) will help you with it).
2. You may not start your app in a certain time, you may only send a toast  notification, alarm or a remainder that your user can tap to enter your app.
3. As the alarm and remainder dialog are both Windows Phone local features, you have no control on them once displayed and therefore, can not react when the snooze button is tapped, for example or control which buttons are displayed.